# Will AWK in shell creat a subprocess?

Tags: shell, awk, subprocess

in my script i write some awk functions to filtering what i want by given key words.
However when I execute my script I found there are multiple process which one is another's parent procees like this and the input paramters are all the same

[image]

When i use pstree to the PPID i found the following ：

[image]

So, my question is : will awk in shell create subprocess ? Does it work like the fork or exec to create a subprocess ?  If not ,how to explain th PID and PPID like this ?

By the way , the script executing on another machine will not generating a subprocess, and pstree the PPID , only find the following content :

[image]

Does it has something to do with the machin's kernal or something like this ? 
Here are some parts of awk in my scripts :

in original_pids i wanna get the old process id by given key words like my_name something that received by parameters:

`original_pids=$(ps -ef | grep ${my_name} | grep -v ${my_pid} | grep  ${instance_id} | grep -F  ${module_name} | grep -F  ${module_path} | grep  -F ${notice_log_paths} | grep -F ${wf_log_paths} | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ')`

and in duration_block i what to get file content in a blockby given the begin and mid line numbers of the file, and the ${cur_last_file} is the received file name

`duration_block=$(awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\\n"} NR=='${begin}',NR=='${mid}' {print $0}' ${cur_last_file}| tr -d '\0')`

Thanks a lot ~~~ :)

```
#!/bin/sh 
headers="Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.binary.v1+json"
file_name="./logs/data1.log"
file_size=$(sed -n "$=" ${file_name})
my_pid=$$
# kafka_proxy is fake here 
kafka_proxy="http://aimer.cp01.com:8989/topics/fake_topic_name"
echo "my_pid=${my_pid}"
sleep 10

begin=1
block=900

while true ; do 
    mid=$[begin+block] 
    duration_block=$(awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\\n"} NR=='${begin}',NR=='${mid}' {print $0}' ${file_name})
    duration_block=$(openssl enc -base64 <<< ${duration_block})
    post_data='{"topic_name":"fake_topic_name","data":"'${duration_block}'"}'
    post_data=$(openssl enc -base64 <<< ${post_data})
    content='{"records":[{"value":'$(echo \"${post_data}\")'}]}'
    #curl -X POST -H "${headers}" -d @- "${kafka_proxy}" <<< ${content}
    #echo "block=${duration_block}"
    begin=${mid}
done
```

Comment: When the shell runs `awk` on your behalf, it creates a new process to do so.  What else happens depends on the context in which `awk` is run, but `awk` is not conventionally part of the shell itself, so it is run as a separate process from the shell.

Comment: That code doesn't even contain `sleep`.

Comment: What you posted isn't an awk script, it's a a couple of shell scripts, the first containing about 20 greps plus pipes plus 1 awk script and 1 tr and the second calling awk and tr. Neither of those awk scripts will spawn sup-processes. The shell will, of course, spawn sub-processes to execute awk and every other command. If you post a new question with it's own [mcve] we can help you do whatever it is you want to do robustly and efficiently - what you have right now is very buggy and inefficient.

Comment: @ Ed Morton yes, you're right , i will refer the link and re-edited my code

Answer (score 0):

I find that the script will create a subprocess when executing curl and awk commands in the script. 
By using the pstree , ps -ef | grep ${name_of_the script} and nohup re-executing the script : 
In image 1 i found that the aimer.sh this script generating a subprocess 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtJfS.png)

And in image2 i create another window use commands like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgYAJ.png) 

`watch -n 1 'pstree ${PPID}'`

to monitor the PPID's child pid

And in image 3 create another window use nohup to see whant happens when PPID generating the child pid by outputing the log in script
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN7C8.png)

After this , i got that when the parent script 
1. use awk and tr to filter contents from upstream file in blocks 
2. use curl to post datas to kafka proxy

The parent script will generate another subprocess.